# Commutation of two vector operator

Tags: operators, commutator

Consider vectors $\overrightarrow { A } $ and $\overrightarrow { B } $ as operators or vector of operators. If this commutation holds$$[\overrightarrow { A },\overrightarrow { B }]=0$$ Then, is that right to claim that commutation of each components are also zero, or it's necessary to be mentioned that the sum of the components commutations are zero. I mean each commutation holds this $$[ A_{i} , B_{j}]=0$$
or the summation holds it.
$$\sum _{ i }\sum _{ j }{[ A_{i} , B_{j}]}=0$$

Comment: That completely depends on what you mean by $[\vec A,\vec B] = 0$. In fact, you might *define* it to hold iff one of the things you write hold. What's *your* definition for $[\vec A,\vec B] = 0$?